# Contour Integral of $z^2 \ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am still pretty new to contour integrals, and I am doing a practice problem but wanted to see if I am doing the steps correctly.

So if I have $C$ be the curve along the parabola $y = x^2$ from $[0, 1]$, and I want to compute $\displaystyle \int_C z^2 \ dz$.

I know that whenever I have a contour integral, it has the form:
\begin{equation*}
\int_C f(z) \ dz = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t) \ dt
\end{equation*}
So we need to parametrize $C$. Since $C$ is defined by $y = x^2$ from $[0, 1]$, the parametrization of $C$ is $z(t) = t + t^2 i$. Then $z'(t) = 1 + 2ti$ and thus, $f(z(t)) = (t + t^2 i)^2$. Therefore, computing the integral we get
\begin{align*}
\int_C z^2 \ dz &= \int_0^1 (t + t^2 i)^2(1 + 2ti) \ dt \\
&= \int_0^1 -5t^4 + t^2 - 2t^5i + 4t^3i \ dt \\
&= \left[-t^5 + \dfrac{1}{3}t^3 - \dfrac{1}{3}t^6i + t^4i\right|_0^1 \\
&= -\dfrac{2}{3} + \dfrac{2}{3}i
\end{align*}
I am not sure if I computed this correctly and if so, does it have to do with my parametrization? Appreciate the help.

Comment: You have computed it correctly. You can check your answer by observing that $z^2$ has an antiderivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is holomorphic in a domain $D \subset \Bbb C$, has an antiderivative $F$ in $D$,  then for any curve $C$ in $D$
$$
 \int_C f(z) \,dz = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t) \,dt = \int_a^b (F\circ z)'(t) \, dt = F(z(b)) - F(z(a))
$$

In other words, if $f$ has an antiderivative then $\int_C f(z) \,dz$ has the same value for all curves joining $z(a)$ and $z(b)$ in $D$, and can be computed analogous to the [second fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part).

In your case is $f(z) = z^2$, which has the antiderivative $F(z) = z^3/3$, so that
$$
\int_C z^2 \,  dz = F(1+i)-F(0) = \frac 13 (1+i)^3 = -\frac 23 + \frac 23 i \, .
$$

So your result is correct, but it does not depend on the parametrization of the curve $C$ and is the same for all curves from $0$ to $1+i$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will try to reword my explanations for the other problems